# How can I poll files, sockets or handles to become readable/writable in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How could I watch several files/sockets from Haskell and wait for these to become readable/writable?

Is there anything like the select/epoll/... in Haskell? Or I am forced to spawn one thread per file/socket and always use the blocking resource from within that thread?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question is wrong: you aren't *forced* to spawn one thread per file/socket and use blocking calls, you *get* to spawn one thread per file/socket and use blocking calls. This is the cleanest solution (in any language); the only reason to avoid it in other languages is that it's a bit inefficient there. GHC's threads are cheap enough, however, that it is not inefficient in Haskell. (Additionally, behind the scenes, GHC's IO manager uses an epoll-alike to wake up threads as appropriate.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :-) I was also thinking from languages like Erlang, where you spawn a light process and it is quite common to receive data from several sockets in the same process.

Comment: Then how do you block on a file descriptor until something happens? Just saying "threads" isn't really answering the question.

Comment: @pdxleif With e.g. `hGetChar` or `hPutChar`.

Comment: That sort of works, but I just want to be notified of an action on the descriptor, not actually read data from it. If I use hGetChar to retrieve data from it, I get an exception "resource exhausted (Resource temporarily unavailable)" when I subsequently run the function that's actually supposed to read the data from it.

Comment: Turns out there's `threadWaitRead` and `threadWaitWrite` in `Control.Concurrent` to block the current thread until a file descriptor is ready for reading / writing, without actually doing reading or writing.

Answer (score 4):

There's a wrapper for `select(2)`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/select
Example usage here: https://github.com/pxqr/udev/blob/master/examples/monitor.hs#L36

There's a wrapper for `poll(2)`:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/poll

GHC base comes with functionality that wraps epoll on Linux (and equivalent on other platforms) in the `GHC.Event` module.
Example usage:

```
import GHC.Event
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

main = do
  fd <- getSomeFileDescriptorOfInterest
  mgr <- fromMaybe (error "Must be compiled with -threaded") <$> getSystemEventManager
  registerFd mgr (\fdkey event -> print event) fd evtRead OneShot
  threadDelay 100000000
```

More documentation at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/GHC-Event.html

Example use of an older version of the lib at https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_Servers#Epoll-based_event_callbacks
Though, the `loop` in that example has since been moved to the hidden module `GHC.Event.Manager`, and is not exported publicly as far as I can tell. `GHC.Event` itself says "This module should be considered GHC internal."

In `Control.Concurrent` there's `threadWaitRead` and `threadWaitWrite`.
So, to translate the above epoll example:

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadWaitRead)

main = do
  fd <- getSomeFileDescriptorOfInterest
  threadWaitRead fd
  putStrLn "Got a read ready event"
```

You can wrap the `threadWaitRead` and subsequent IO action in `Control.Monad.forever` to run them repeatedly. You can also wrap the thing in `forkIO` to run it in the background while your program does something else.

Comment: Turns out there's `threadWaitRead` and `threadWaitWrite` in `Control.Concurrent` to block the current thread until a file descriptor is ready for reading / writing, without actually doing reading or writing.

Comment: `select` is POSIX function, is it possible to use this package `select` in Windows? Haskell is MinGW based, so I hope it could work, but I am not sure...

Comment: I would just use `Control.Concurrent.threadWaitRead` - which is already part of GHC, and should be cross-platform. I would not recommend use of that `select` library.