# Concurrent (multithreaded) program hangs unless I print something

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

I have a function that I fork off into a thread using [forkIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO). The function runs in a [ReaderT monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#t:ReaderT) so that I can pass in a read-only configuration record:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    ...
    forkIO $ runReaderT watcher config
```

The `watcher` function watches an MVar using [tryTakeMVar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#v:tryTakeMVar) (I don't want it to block.) The MVar is stored in the config and is called "drawer" because it behaves like a transaction drawer between `main` and the thread that `watcher` is watching in, basically a skip channel.

`printThing` has a signature of `printThing :: Thing -> ReaderT Config IO ()` and calls `putStrLn` to print a `Thing`.

```
watcher :: ReaderT Config IO ()                                                                                                                                                                       
 watcher = do
     cfg <- ask
     mNewThing <- liftIO $ tryTakeMVar $ drawer cfg
     case mNewThing of
         Nothing -> do
            --liftIO $ putStr ""  -- uncommenting this helps
            watcher
         Just newThing -> do
             printThing newThing
             watcher
```

The problem is that the program hangs when it runs. It seems to be stuck in a loop. Calling `putStr ""` in `main` doesn't help, HOWEVER, calling `putStr ""`  inside `watcher` does trigger the thread -- it starts spinning and printing out `Thing`s as expected.

All I can figure is that I'm getting bitten by laziness, but I'm not sure where. I've tried using `$!` where possible.

**I do IO actions in certain conditions of `watcher`, but not all of them. Is that the problem? I need to do IO actions in ALL conditions branches?**

If it helps,  I didn't have this problem before I wrapped everything up in the `ReaderT` transformer. I was just passing `config` around as an argument.

Comment: My guess it that you're getting bitten by the fact that there is [no context switching](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#g:4) happening. Can you try inserting calls to [`yield`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:yield) instead of `putStr ""` to see if that works?

Comment: Are you using threaded or non-threaded runtime? In case of threaded one, are you using more then one capability? IIRC in case of threaded runtime with more then 1 capability enabled, `tryTakeMVar` will yield, otherwise it won't.

Comment: Could be this [known bug](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bugs.html#bugs-in-ghc) (first item). Try `-fno-omit-yields`, or manually insert a `yield`.

Comment: Why don't you want `watcher` to block?

Comment: in fact, `watcher` does block. calling `tryTakeMVar` in an endless loop is just a not so efficient way to block on an MVar.

Comment: @theindigamer You guessed right, inserting `yield` helps the program run as expected.

Comment: @chi `-fno-omit-yields` in my project's cabal file didn't seem to help, but manually inserting a yield did.

Comment: @chi Hm, `-fno-omit-yields` works when I put it in the file with OPTIONS_GHC. Not sure why it doesn't work in the cabal file.

Comment: is it really helping if you just give the OP the *feeling* that he got help? Because `-fno-omit-yields` isn't a proper solution. The function still blocks. I think there is a problem in IT, where when someone asks a nonsensical question, we feel the urge to respond in a limited way instead of explaining things properly. Like when someone asks "how can I put a finger in a wallsocket without getting an electric shock", an IT person would answer "use isolating gloves". But that doesn't help the person to see wether the wallsocket contains current.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the text in your question, I recommend that you let `watcher` block. It is quite rare indeed to need non-blocking operations on `MVar`s; usually wanting it is a [sign you haven't quite internalized the "fork everything" mentality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11744527/791604). So:

```
watcher :: ReaderT Config IO ()
watcher = do
    cfg <- ask
    newThing <- liftIO . takeMVar $ drawer cfg
    printThing newThing
    watcher
```

We can separately address a question of the form "How do I achieve effect X, that seems to me to need non-blocking operations, while only using blocking operations?" if you will write up a separate question with some details about effect X.

Side note: I'd be tempted to write the above in the following way, which has the same meaning but appeals to me more aesthetically:

```
watcher = forever (asks drawer >>= liftIO . takeMVar >>= printThing)
```

Comment: doesn't `watcher` block in any case? polling in an endless loop indefinitely is a way of blocking, according to my definition.

Comment: @Michael The usual definition of "blocking", in concurrent systems, is asking the OS/RTS/scheduler to remove the current thread  from the list of active threads until some event happens. Busy waiting is not "blocking", and there's an extensive literature about avoiding wasting CPU time using a busy wait, which has influenced Haskell primitives. Daniel's code above runs `takeMVar` each loop, so it's blocking whenever there's nothing to do instead of polling/busy waiting.